# How can I check two float is exactly equal?

Tags: python

I write below program but My program cannot check the two number is equal or not.
There is no error,
I would be appreciate for any help.

```
import math
def IsCollinding(ball1,ball2):
  distance=math.sqrt((((ball2[0]-ball1[0])**2)+((ball2[1]-ball1[1])**2)))
  print(type(distance))
  print(type(ball1[2]+ball2[2]))
  if(distance==ball1[2]+ball2[2]):
    print("Is Coliding")
  else:
    print("Not Coliding")
  print(distance)
  print(ball1[2]+ball2[2])
ball1=[2,2,3]
ball2=[11,11,9.7279220614]
IsCollinding(ball1,ball2)
```

output:

```
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
Not Coliding
12.7279220614
12.7279220614
```

Comment: Add comments maybe to help us understand what is going on?

Answer (score 6):

You can not really do this. Floats may appear equal, but are actually different due to [floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). However, you can cheat. We can call two numbers "equal" if the difference between the two is very small.

The function looks like this:

```
(x - y) < delta
```

Where `delta` is a small number. Implemented in Python:

```
def almost_equal(x, y, delta=1e-10):
    return abs(x - y) < delta
```

I use `abs` here to get the absolute value of the difference. We avoid having to deal with negative numbers and the order of the `x` and `y` arguments this way.

Comparing two floats is one of the most [common gotchas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_(programming)), and is something most of us run into at one point. Googling "[comparing two floats python](https://www.google.no/search?q=comparing%20two%20floats%20python)" should have returned plenty of informative results about this topic.